# WebSocket events not firing sporadically

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I searched for a while but couldn't find a working solution for my particular problem.

I have the "default" WebSocket implementation in my JavaScript file. It works but it does not work everytime. Sometimes (can be the first time but could also be the 101st time) the event don't fire. Shouldn't at least the onclose-event fire with wasClean == false?

Maybe someone can help me out with this.

Edit: Forgot something. Only happens if I provide a wrong IP-Adress for:
`ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + ip + ":9999/");`

So server-side code is not necessary to answer this question.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + ip + ":9999/");

    ws.onopen = function(evt) {
        console.log("CONNECTED");
        doSend("getInfo");
    };

    ws.onclose = function(evt) {
        if (!evt.wasClean) {
            showError();
            return;
        }

        console.log("DISCONNECTED");
    };

    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
        newIP = evt.data;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

Problem was that the no-route-to-host error wasn't firing fast enough if there is no device behind the given IP-Adress. So I implemented a timeout which checks if the readyState of the socket is zero after 100 ms (Application runs in a Local Area Network so the time should be large enough)

```
function checkServer(ip, port) {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + ip + ":" + port);

    setTimeout(function() {
       if (ws.readyState == 0) {
          showError();
       }
       else {
          ws.close();
          ConnectToServer();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```